# How do I filter based in Indices in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an issue with manipulating indices once I have used the groupby command. My problem is similar to this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1000000,5)),columns=list('ABCDE'))
M=df.groupby(['A','B','D','E'])['C'].sum().unstack()
M
```

```
E        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
A B D                                                  
0 0 0  464  414  553  420  499  394  528  423  415  443
    1  407  479  392  441  433  472  520  421  484  384
    2  545  546  523  356  386  434  531  534  486  417
    3  408  511  422  424  477  351  452  395  341  492
    4  502  462  403  434  428  444  506  414  418  328
...    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
9 9 5  419  416  485  386  581  330  408  489  394  454
    6  416  475  469  490  357  523  418  514  555  499
    7  528  419  462  486  565  388  438  445  469  521
    8  390  454  566  341  459  463  478  463  426  499
    9  414  436  441  462  403  415  362  472  433  430

[1000 rows x 10 columns]
```

I am wondering how to filter down to only situations where B is greater than A, when they are both in the index here. If they weren't in the index then I would be doing something like M=M[M['A']<M['B']].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily convert the index [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html):

```
out = M.loc[M.index.to_frame().query('B>A').index]
```

Or use [`Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
A = M.index.get_level_values('A')
B = M.index.get_level_values('B')

out = M.loc[B>A]
```

Output:

```
E        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
A B D                                                  
0 1 0  489  452  421  455  442  377  440  476  477  451
    1  468  448  473  443  557  492  471  460  476  469
    2  576  472  465  355  503  448  491  437  546  425
    3  404  438  474  516  410  446  411  459  467  450
    4  500  418  441  445  420  605  467  580  479  377
...    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
8 9 5  390  466  436  493  446  508  375  390  485  393
    6  457  478  476  417  458  460  361  397  432  403
    7  516  587  379  406  396  449  430  433  357  432
    8  390  460  489  427  346  490  498  454  395  345
    9  474  510  466  336  484  577  443  428  459  406

[450 rows x 10 columns]
```